# Get value from selected row DataGridView WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, datagridview

I have event in DataGridView MouseDoubleClick and when I click on any row I wanna receive a value from 1 column.

My datasource is from `WZ_DWS_SITO` class. I have created a method that extracts data from the database:

```
public void getdata()
    {

        EntitiesSito db = new EntitiesSito();

        var query = (from d in db.WZ_DWS_SITO
                     orderby d.WZ_DATA descending
                     group d by new { d.WZ, d.KUNNR, d.WZ_DATA } into grp
                     select new
                     {
                         grp.Key.WZ,
                         grp.Key.KUNNR,
                         grp.Key.WZ_DATA,
                         MATERIAL = grp.Count(),
                     }).ToList();

        datagridview.ItemsSource = query; 

    }
```

Next I want when I click on row element I want recive cell value from 1 column.

I try this :

```
var wz = (datagridview.SelectedItem as WZ_DWS_SITO).WZ;
```

But is not working :/ I recive an error :

```
The object reference has not been set to the instance of the object.
```

Next i try :

```
WZ_DWS_SITO wka = (WZ_DWS_SITO)datagridview.SelectedItem;
```

And I get a projection error and I do not know what's going on until the end: /

Please help :)

Comment: You're selecting into an anonymous type. That isn't going to be WZ_DWS_SITO. Make it a specific type.

Comment: If you change this `WZ_DWS_SITO wka = (WZ_DWS_SITO)datagridview.SelectedItem;` to `dynamic wka = datagridview.SelectedItem;` it will work.

Comment: It works, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using `select new` keywords you do not deal with `WZ_DWS_SITO` class more, but with the new anonymous one.

First, create a class for your data:

```
   public class GroupedData 
   { 
      public string WZ {get; set;} 
      public string KUNNR {get; set;} 
      public string WZ_DATA {get; set;} 
      public int MATERIAL {get; set;} 
   }
```

then change the query:

```
select new GroupedData()
                     {
                         WZ = grp.Key.WZ,
                         KUNNR = grp.Key.KUNNR,
                         DATA = grp.Key.WZ_DATA,
                         MATERIAL = grp.Count(),
                     }
```

and use

```
GroupedData wka = (GroupedData)(datagridview.SelectedItem);
```

Comment: How it works ?  Where I may read about this and improve my knowledge ?

Comment: If you mean LINQ, I can advice you this book: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920024064.do (it's not new, but I like it) or this tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/linq/index.htm

Comment: Thanks for advice :)